Jenkin can not rename folder as tutorial eventhough user can rename the folder as usual?
I am newbie with Jenkin and here is my problem.
I am follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BNmVWA06io and trying to add code step by step, but my problem is, when I ran the Jenkin, it did not work and gave me this error:
java.io.IOException: Failed to rename C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\Node\node-v21.7.3-win-x64 to C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\Node\node-v21.7.3-win-x64.__rename

When I tried to rename the folder "node-v21.7.3-win-x64" to "node-v21.7.3-win-x64.__rename", it was normal, so maybe it is because of the program?
Here is the git folder's link
https://github.com/kavisuresh/SampleExpressApp

And the tutorial's link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BNmVWA06io

Could you please give me some advices? Thank you in advance.
